# re-render nested template as data changes

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-blaze

I am using a nested template and passing data using {{#with}} but even when data changes nested template is not rendered again. Should not it render everytime data is changing?

```
{{#with selectedBooth}}
<div id ="chatRoom" class="col-md-9 no-mar-pad white_bgg right_part">
   {{> textChat}}
</div>
{{/with}}
```

I am expecting the rendered of textChat template to run as and when selectedBooth is changing. how to achieve that?

like structure of selectedBooth is:

```
{ channelId: 'xxx', otherUser: <json object>}
```

so now i want to make subscription as channelId is changing but as rendered is not invoked, I have to make subscription in parent template which gets the new channel data and retain old channels data as well which I dont want.
Also I need to reset some variables in textChat as data context changes.

I thought template would be destroyed and created again whenever data changes. Is that not correct? Is there some way to destroy template so that rendered is invoked everytime data context changes?

Comment: Not a lot of information here, but if selectedBooth changes, the data context does change. If selectedBooth has a name field and you write {{name}} in the with scope, you'll see it update automatically when selectedBooth changes.

Comment: Data does changes in textChat as the selectedBooth changes but rendered is not called again. I want to reset some variables and make subscription on the basis of value in selectedBooth. but since rendered is invoked only first time, I am not able to do that

Comment: Ok. This is for performance reasons. Before blaze templates did rerender multiple times. There are definitely ways around your problem. You might need to use a reactive variable to see when a change was made.